# PostgreSQL - Calculating number of institutions that sold counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

We have a table called 'holdings'.
It contains the information of number of shares held by financial institutions in companies for each quarter.

which has the following columns:

| institution_id | symbol | shares | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAPL | 0 | 2020_Q4 |
| 2 | TSLA | 200000 | 2020_Q4 |
| 1 | AAPL | 100000 | 2020_Q3 |

We want to calculate the no. of institutions that have sold their holdings in a particular company (represented by symbol) in a particular quarter.
We have a query like this currently, but I think it can be improved.

```
select count(*) as "soldCount",sum(q3.shares) as "soldShares" from 
        (select * from holdings 
         where quarter='2020_Q3'
        and symbol='AAPL') q3
        left join (select * from holdings 
         where quarter='2020_Q4'
        and symbol='AAPL') q4
        on q3.institution_id=q4.institution_id
        where 
         q3.shares>0 
        and (q4.shares=0 or q4.shares is null)
```

Additional info:
Table 'holdings' is partitioned by 'quarter'.
Indices are created on 'institution_id', 'symbol' and 'quarter'.
Combination of columns (institution_id, symbol, quarter) is unique.

Any help is appreciated very much.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: Improvement in terms of performance obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use aggregation.  To get the institutions themselves:

```
select symbol, institution, sum(shares) as q3_shares
from hodings
where quarter in ('2020_Q3', '2020_Q4') and
      symbol = 'AAPL'
group by symbol, institution
having sum(shares) filter (where quarter = '2020_Q3') = sum(shares) and
       sum(shares) > 0;
```

The logic for the having clause is:  "All the shares are in '2020_Q3' and there is at least one share".

Then if you want the totals, a second level of aggregation:

```
select symbol, count(*), sum(q3_shares)
from (select symbol, institution, sum(shares) as q3_shares
      from hodings
      where quarter in ('2020_Q3', '2020_Q4') and
            symbol = 'AAPL'
      group by symbol, institution
      having sum(shares) filter (where quarter = '2020_Q3') = sum(shares) and
             sum(shares) > 0
     ) si;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for a lot cleaner query. But performance wise, it's same as our query in the question. Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: @ShanmukhMeesala . . . Do you have an index on `holdings(symbol, quarter, institution)`?

Comment: Yes @Gordon, I have index on holdings(symbol, quarter, institution_id)

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff, I got the issue. In the where condition I'm using "UPPER(symbol) = 'AAPL'". Because of "UPPER", it's not using the index. Now I just replaced symbol with UPPER(symbol) in the data it self.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `EXISTS` performs better than a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "soldCount",
       SUM(q3.shares) AS "soldShares" 
FROM holdings q3
WHERE q3.quarter='2020_Q3' AND q3.symbol='AAPL' AND q3.shares>0
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM holdings q4 
    WHERE q4.institution_id=q3.institution_id
      AND q4.quarter='2020_Q4' AND q4.symbol='AAPL'
      AND q4.shares<>0
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, But it has same performance as my query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use window function lead in next way:

```
select * from (
  select 
      holdings.*,
      -- use lead for retrieve previous quarter shares 
      lead(shares) over (partition by institution_id, symbol order by quarter desc) previous_quarter
  from holdings
  where symbol = 'AAPL'
) copmarsion 
-- limit records where shares less when previous_quarter
where shares < coalesce(previous_quarter, 0);
```

[PostgeSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=0bf16abb01a16df12a05029a4c3768c2&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "soldCount",SUM(T1.shares) as "soldShares" FROM holdings T1
LEFT JOIN holdings T2 ON T1.institution_id = T2.institution_id
WHERE (T1.quarter = '2020_Q3' AND T1.symbol = 'AAPL') OR (T2.quarter = '2020_Q4' AND T2.symbol = 'AAPL')
AND T1.shares > 0  AND (T2.shares = 0 OR T2.shares IS NULL)
```

Comment: It won't work as rows corresponding to 0 shares won't exist in the table

Comment: I used AND instead of OR. It works now. Seasons 2020_Q3 or 2020_Q4